# How do I create email addresses for all my users using my domain (username@mydomain.com)?

Tags: email, hosting, dotnetnuke

My client wants to create email addresses for all their dotnetnuke users using their domain. The point is to keep the user's email addresses 'private' while still allowing communication through a public email address that they can control.

It's not necessary to have a full webmail interface (although that would be nice).  I'm thinking it would be enough just to forward any mail on and just act as a gateway. So if an email was sent to rwain@mydomain.com, it would be forwarded on to the email address associated with the dotnetnuke account with username 'rwain'.

Is this possible to do in a shared hosting environment? Or do I need to create some custom mail server that does a conversion of the email address and forwards it?

Comment: It's usually possible, you'll have to contact your host to ask how to set it up, because it will be different for every one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else is looking for a solution here, I've contacted a hosting company and they have told me that unless I want to create the email addresses for each DNN user manually, it's not possible in a shared hosting environment.

However, a VPS hosting solution makes it possible to automatically create email addresses using the SmarterMail API:

http://www.smartertools.com/smartermail/mail-server-software.aspx

Answer (score 1):

A library like MailBee .NET mail object by AfterLogic - http://www.afterlogic.com/ might help - I have had good luck with it - it really is going to depend on the hosting environment though and the mail server

Answer (score 1):

You could always go the route of using [Google Apps](http://www.google.com/apps) as well.  I've used this on many personal and professional DotNetNuke sites.